# Angular $watchGroup and deleted variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
listener=$rootScope.$watchGroup(['user','geolocation'],function(newvalue,oldvalue) {
  if (angular.isDefined(newvalue[0]) && angular.isDefined(newvalue[1]) {
    ... Do Something...
  }
}
```

I am basically waiting for two promises to finish, which load $rootScope.user and $rootScope.geolocation.  Once these are done, I want to do something.

The problem is, the $rootScope.user change is seen, but the $rootScope.geolocation change is never seen.

I'm now thinking it might have something to do with the way the $rootScope.geolocation is being handled.  If $rootScope.geolocation is an object.  If I replace $rootScope.geolocation, and it gets associated with a new object, what happens to the watch?

Can the watch lose it's connection with what it's supposed to be watching?

I notice that if I do a `<div ng-bind="$root.geolocation"></div>`, it disappears during the time when it's being reset, and does not reappear.

How can I avoid this, so that my binding / watch actually works?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you trigger events on `$rootScope` once your promises are finished by using `$broadcast`:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('myEvent');
```

Then, just listen to `myEvent` and do your stuff:

```
$rootScope.$on('myEvent', function(newvalue, oldvalue) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

Further information in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use `$q.all` which takes an array of promises as a parameter and call `then` on what's returned. Documentation is [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)